# How do I disable or turn off Burst Mode photos in iPhone 6s?

Tags: photos, camera, iphone

Whenever I use the self-timer modes (either 3s, or 10s), my iPhone takes a burst of photos no matter what. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 4):

Enabling the flash is one way to disable burst photos in **Timer** mode. You can also force HDR *On*.

I much prefer enabling **HDR** for this purpose, as it often yields better photos anyway. LED flash can drastically alter your scene in ways that may not be pleasing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6674023?start=0&tstart=0

"Turn the flash to "ON" and photo burst is disabled."

Answer (score 0):

For jailbroken iOS devices there are several free tweaks available in Cydia that have the option to disable burst mode:

- http://cydia.saurik.com/package/org.thebigboss.moretimer8
- http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.pxcex.cameramode10